# My Shepard's face changes DURING the game

Tags: mass-effect-3

So I imported my character from ME2 to ME3, made some edits to the face, and played with it. No problem, until recently, where in some conversations my face is just totally changed (and... ugly.)

I will add pictures as soon as I manage to replicate the problem (just finished the game, so..), but basically, the eyes and face have a totally different shape, no lips anymore, apparent teeth..

I noticed that it happens mainly when wearing an armor. It also seemed to start when I started wearing the Recon Hood. It doesn't happen all the time: it can be for a whole mission, only for a few dialogs, or none at all. My settings are on "Default helmet off in conversations", and I'm playing on PC.

Does anyone have any idea why it is happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: What kind of changes are we talking about here? Do you have screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced that, it seems to be a bug in the game. Restarting the game fixes it. It happens only rarely so it's not a big issue. Hopefully they will fix it permanently with a patch.

Comment: I doubt there will be any more patches to ME3